# Change reason for ISO 639 Hebrew language code from iw-IL to he-IL

Tags: hebrew, standards

I saw that in 1989, the [ISO 639 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) [changed](http://xml.coverpages.org/iso639a.html#:%7E:text=HAUSA%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20HA%20%20%20%20%20NEGRO%2DAFRICAN-,HEBREW%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20HE%20%20%20%20%20SEMITIC%20%5B*Changed%201989%20from%20original%20ISO%20639%3A1988%2C%20IW%5D,-HINDI%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20HI%20%20%20%20%20INDIAN%0AHUNGARIAN) the code for for [Afro-Asiatic Hebrew (עברית)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes#:%7E:text=Hebrew-,%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA,-he) from `iw-IL` to `he-IL`. I was trying to look for the reasons for this change but I couldn’t find any.

- Was `iw-IL` insulting somehow?
- `IL` is for Israel and `he` is for Hebrew, but what does `iw` mean?

Comment: I don't know about the standard's history, but the code *iw* is obviously pointing to *Ivrit*, the modern Hebrew word for "Hebrew". Don't know why it came with a *w* instead of a *v*, but transliteration practices change over time, too.

Comment: Thank you for the info about the `iw`, very interesting! So, definitely, `iw` is **not** offensive in any aspect, right?

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica the v in Ivrit is a bet-rafuyah rather than a vav though, so the use of w for it is not part of any romanisation standard (although it may happen in some ad hoc Polish transcriptions for instance), and no pronunciation pronounces it with a /w/ so the use of a w is very odd here

Comment: @Tristan: And also older German transcription didn't differentiate v and w, I remember that I saw *Iwrith* in a German context (and it is still mentioned as an alternate transcription in the German Wikipedia).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`iw` comes from *Iwrit* or *Iwrith*, a somewhat-archaic German borrowing of עברית‎ (the more common German term nowadays, in my experience, is *Hebräische*). In the 1989 revisions, two of the changes involved replacing codes based on German names with codes based on English ones: Yiddish changed from `ji` to `yi`, and Hebrew from `iw` to `he`.

The earlier ones presumably came from some older standard from a German-speaking place, but despite the "I" in "ISO", these standards are primarily influenced by English-speakers; if a language doesn't use the Latin alphabet and has a widely-recognized English exonym, the code will often be based on that. For example, the code `cr` comes from English "Cree" rather than ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐍᐏᐣ (Nehiyawewin) or its local variants, and `ja` comes from English "Japanese" rather than にほんご (Nihongo). I have no sources for the motivation, but I imagine they decided to regularize things by requiring the codes to be based on either native endonyms or English exonyms/transcriptions, not German ones.

I can't see any reason why `iw` would be insulting or offensive; it comes from a transcription of עברית, which is the usual name in Modern Hebrew. It's just no longer standard.

Comment: When we speak in German about the Hebrew spoken in Isreal right now, we say *Neuhebräisch*, *Hebräisch* alone still suggests Biblical Hebrew to most German speakers.